# Typescript: Compile Utility Types into module's declaration file

Tags: typescript

This might just be wishful thinking:

I have a module `foo` that uses the Parameters<> from a different mod `bar`, and passes it out of the current mod (`foo`).  So now if some new mod `baz` requires `foo`, it has to Also install the @types for the mod that `foo` is using: `bar` in order to figure out the Parameters<> Type.  This feels like a common situation, and I was hoping there was a way to handle it that didn't involve forcing `baz` to need all the declarations from `bar`, like a way that the extracted types compiled into `foo`'s declaration maybe.  Greatly appreciate any guidance!

**module bar** index.ts:

```
export function doSomething(param: any) { }
```

**module foo** index.ts:

```
import { doSomething } from "bar"
export function DoAnotherThing(param: Parameters<typeof doSomething>[0]) {
    doSomething(param)
}
```

**module baz** index.ts

```
import { doAnotherThing } from "foo"

// if @types/bar isn't also installed:
// Type 'unknown' has no matching index signature for type 'number'
doAnotherThing(123)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let the dependency tree just do its work. You don't need any special magic here.

You should just need to add `@types/bar` in the `devDependencies` of the `foo` module. Now `npm install foo` should install `foo`, `bar` and `@types/bar`, and everything should work just fine.

Comment: thanks for the response!  That's surprising and very helpful to know that this should be working.  Maybe my setup is what's causing the problem then: I'm pulling modules and types from my own github repo, ex: "@mytypes/foo" and "@myapps/foo", and I have to manually add the "@mytypes" directory to typeRoots in every mod's tsconfig.  And the tsconfig doesn't exist for imported modules, so it probably can't find the declaration?  Would including the tsconfig in the package fix it?  Pretty lost on this one.

Comment: --edit-- my type declarations have their own/separate empty package.json for the "@mytypes" package, so there's no way to follow the dependency tree.  I need to find a different way to split up the JS files from the D.TS files than using two package.json files.